# How to output and input values of textboxes / comboboxes in wpf

Tags: c#, wpf

So I made a program that contains a lot of textboxes and comboboxes for some calculations. The program has an Output button and an Input button. At the moment I have managed the Input through skipping lines and inserting the information like this:

```
ComboBoxes like this.
if (File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(23).Take(1).First() == "TEMP")
                {
                    TEMP5.SelectedIndex = 2;
                }

Textboes like this.
                TEMP1.Text = File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(25).Take(1).First();
```

and the Output is just a massive block of Output containing newlines

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename,bla bla bla
```

Is there a better way?? There has to be.

EDIT: So one button "Output" saves all data contained in textboxes and comboboxes in a txt file.

The "Input" button makes you able to choose the txt file and copy the data into the boxes.

Comment: I'm having a bit of trouble understanding exactly what you're trying to do. Could you please edit your question to be a bit more clear?

Comment: Secondly, `File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(23).Take(1).First()` can be simplified to `File.ReadLines(filename)[23]`. Likewise, `File.ReadLines(filename).Skip(25).Take(1).First()` can be simplified to `File.ReadLines(filename)[25]`.

Comment: Good, now what part of the code are you trying to improve? What part do you think should have a “better way”?

Comment: The Output part. i have too many lines of code like this `+ "\r\n-- TESTTYPE --------------------------\r\n" + TEST1.Text + "\r\n" + TEST2.Text +`

Comment: File.ReadLines(filename)[25] does not work for me

Comment: What about it doesn't work? Do you get an exception?

Comment: Severity Code Description Project File Line Suppression State
Error CS0021 Indexing with [] cannot be applied to an Expression of type IEnumerable<string>. NHF Tool C:-XXX-source-repos-XXX.MainWindow.xaml.cs 2799 Active

Comment: Oops, that's my mistake. `ReadLines` returns an `IEnumerable` not an `IList`, so you can't use `[]`. You could do `File.ReadLines(filename).ToList()[23]`, or just do what you were already doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I usually find that if someone has to name boxes "Box1", "Box2", "Box3"... "Box99" then their doing something wrong. Unless each value has a specific, unique calculation that needs to be done with it, you can usually make things cleaner with a list.

In WPF, you can use `ItemsControl`s like `DataGrid` to generate rows of `TextBox`s that will link back to your list with data binding. If that looks like something that might fit, I would highly recommend looking into it. It will save you a lot of work in the long run.

That being said, if you do have a series of controls named consecutively ("Box1", "Box2", "Box3", etc), you can use `FindName()` to access them dynamically:

```
var outputBuilder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 1; i < 100; i++)
{
    ComboBox box = (ComboBox)FindName("TEST" + i.ToString());
    outputBuilder.AppendLine(box.Text);
}

System.IO.File.WriteAllText(filename, outputBuilder.ToString());
```

Comment: It is more complicated than you would think since every box has his own dependency of checkboxes etc so it is not box1 to box99. Back to your code: doesn't append just append the text in the same line?? If i am not being clear enough sorry: each TextBox Needs his own line so i can say BOX5 = the string in line 5 of the text file for example.

Comment: [`AppendLine(string)`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder.appendline?view=netframework-4.8#System_Text_StringBuilder_AppendLine_System_String_): "Appends a copy of the specified string followed by the default line terminator". It will append the text, then make a new line.

Comment: The code you posted does not work for me. It says an object can't be converted to "System.Windows.Controls.Combobox" underlining the FindName("TEST" + i.ToString());

Comment: ComboBox box = (ComboBox)this.FindName("TEST" + i.ToString()); did the trick

Comment: Sorry about that, I've corrected the code in my answer.